# Google Maps w/Database of Coord. Live Updates

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I currently have deployed a webapp that shows locations of our field employees using geoLocation (HTML5) and ajax to post to a PHP script that stores the location in a database.

The map updates the location of the employees if you do a full refresh of the page, but I can't figure out how to have the page show the markers moving in real time?

HERE IS THE JS.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(position) {

     //alert("position is: " + position.coords.latitude + ", " + position.coords.longitude);

    $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "/includes/functions/js.locationServices/locationServices.php",  
                data: "latitude="+ position.coords.latitude +"&longitude="+ position.coords.longitude
              });                  
});
```

The php code is a simple get and update database.

GOOGLE MAP CODE

```
function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
    $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 

return $xmlStr; 
} 

    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM authUsers JOIN techLocation ON authUsers.username = techLocation.username");
        $sql->execute();

    header("Content-type: text/xml");

    echo '<markers>';

    while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
        $time = date("g:i a", strtotime($row['lastLocated']));
        $tech = $row['id'];

        if(is_numeric($row['id'])) { $tech = '#'.$row['id']; }

        echo '<marker ';
        echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['fullname']) . '" ';
        echo 'tech="' . parseToXML($tech) . '" ';
        echo 'phone="' . parseToXML($row['phone']) . '" ';
        echo 'email="' . parseToXML($row['email']) . '" ';
        echo 'time="' . parseToXML($time) . '" ';
        echo 'lat="' . $row['latitude'] . '" ';
        echo 'lng="' . $row['longitude'] . '" ';
        echo 'type="' . $row['dept'] . '" ';
        echo '/>';
    }

    echo '</markers>';
```

MAP PAGE

```
    <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var customIcons = {
      Installs: {
        icon: '/location/images/installs.png',
        shadow: '/location/images/shadow50.png'
      },
      Service: {
        icon: '/location/images/service.png',
        shadow: '/location/images/shadow50.png'
      }
    };

    var markers = new Array();

    function updateMarker(techSelectionList) {      
            var selectedEmail = techSelectionList.options[techSelectionList.selectedIndex].value;
            var selectedText = techSelectionList.options[techSelectionList.selectedIndex].text;


            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
            {
                var techEmail = markers[i].getTitle();


                if (techEmail == selectedEmail)
                {
                    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
                    break;
                }
            }
    }

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $mapCenter; ?>),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) 
      {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markersXml = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
        sidebar.innerHTML = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < markersXml.length; i++) 
        {          
            var name = markersXml[i].getAttribute("name");
                var phone = markersXml[i].getAttribute("phone");
            var email = markersXml[i].getAttribute("email");
                var tech = markersXml[i].getAttribute("tech");
                var time = markersXml[i].getAttribute("time");
                var type = markersXml[i].getAttribute("type");
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markersXml[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(markersXml[i].getAttribute("lng"))
            );

            var html = "<h3>" + name + " - "+ tech + " </h3><br/>Phone:<b> <a href='tel:" + phone + "'>" + phone + "</a></b><br/>Email:<b> <a href='mailto:" + email + "'>" + email + "</a></b><br/>Located:<b> " + time + "</b>";
                var icon = customIcons[type] || {};

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon,
                shadow: icon.shadow
            });

            marker.setTitle(email);
            markers.push(marker);

            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

            var sidebarEntry = createSidebarEntry(marker, tech, name, email);
            sidebar.appendChild(sidebarEntry);      
        }           

    });

    function createSidebarEntry(marker, tech, name, email) 
    {
        var text =  tech + " - " + name;                
        var div = document.createElement('option');
        div.text = text;
        div.value = email;

        return div;
    }
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
//]]>

</script>
```

Comment: Two things to note: #1, There's no reason to do those string replaces, You can do all that with one single function - `$xmlstr = htmlentities($htmlstr, ENT_QUOTES)`. This will convert all HTML entities including single and double quotes. The answer to your question is in your ajax function, it provides a `success:function(data)` property. The `data` in the success will provide you with whatever you send back from the server. So when you do your insert, just format the coordinates to come back in your ajax string and it will do the updates in the map.

Comment: the script that does the ajax call is in my header file that loads whenever a page on the site loads (to grab the latest coordinates). The google map is generated on a separate page using the database.

So i just need to modify that page to somehow refresh the marker locations in realtime, but I am not sure how. thought google maps supported this, but all I can find is updating your own position on the map and not a map full of users moving around. Ugh, wish this easier. 

Thank you for the tip though, I changed my code to use htmlentities instead.